# Abelianization of the $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$#$\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I know that the fundamental group of $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$#$\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$ is $<a,b|a^2b^2>$.

When we abelianize this we have this presentation: $Ab(\pi_1(\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$#$\mathbb R \mathbb P^2)=<a,b|a^2b^2, ab=ba>$.

However, we know that the $H_1(\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$#$\mathbb R \mathbb P^2)=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z_2$ (Amstrong's book page 183), i.e.,

$Ab(\pi_1(\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$#$\mathbb R \mathbb P^2)=<a,b|b^2,ab=ba>$.

Both has to be equivalent, but I don't know why.

I need help here.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The first version can be seen as $\langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle/(a^2b^2)$, which is $\mathbb Z^2/\mathbb Z(2,2)$, identifying the images of $a$ and $b$ in the abelianization of the free group with $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Doing the same for the second version, we get $\mathbb Z^2/\mathbb Z(0,2)$.

Now there is an automorphism of $\mathbb Z^2$ which maps $(2,2)$ to $(0,2)$, so from it you can get an iso.

Comment: What is $\mathbb Z(2,2)$? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: $(2,2)$ is an element of $\mathbb Z^2$, $\mathbb Z(2,2)$ is the subgroup generated by it. One could write this $((2,2))$, but that look silly!

Comment: I can't see why $\langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle/(a^2b^2)$ is $\mathbb Z^2/\mathbb Z(2,2)$.

Comment: Can you see why $A=\langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$?

Comment: yes, of course!

Comment: Pick the obvious isomorphism $\mathbb Z^2\to A$, What is the image of the subgroup $\mathbb Z(2,2)$?

Comment: I don't know. I  tried a lot without success. Maybe because I didn't understand this isomorphism properly. How can I build this isomorphism? sorry about my doubts, group presentations for me is a little bit weird.

Comment: Can you tell me what isomorphism you *of course* see?

Comment: I know there is a isomorphism because $A$ is generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ and because of the word $ab=ba$ this group is abelian, so it should be $Z^2$ but I don't know how to construct this isomorphism, did you follow me?

Comment: Well: before going on you should make explicit an isomorphism.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to say to you, I know there is an isomorphism, but I don't know how to explicit it :(

Comment: $f:\mathbb Z^2\to A$ such that $f(a,1)=a$? is it correct?